# Combinatorics problem, contacts increase by 5 how many times to reach 1 billion?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am having difficulty with the following problem:
"Suppose that you have five contacts in your professional network. Each of these contacts (first degree) is linked to five additional exclusive contacts (second degree), which again are linked to five additional exclusive contacts each, etc. How many degrees are needed for you to reach 1 billion people in your extended network?"

I do not know how to approach the problem, the only idea that I had was to divide 1 billion by 5 but I am certain that it is wrong. Can you also explain the thinking behind it please? Thank you.

Comment: How many second degree contacts do you have?

Comment: This is a sum of geometric series if you look carefully. Try writing down the number of contacts in each degree first.

Comment: It is 5x5 so 25 contacts. (I copied the question word to word from my book)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$ degree: $5$ contacts.
$2$ degrees: $5 + 5^2$ contacts.
$3$ degrees: $5 + 5^2 + 5^3$ contacts.

So we need to solve $$\sum_{k=1}^x 5^k = 1000000000$$ Using the formula for geometric series, we have
$$\frac 54 (5^x - 1)= 1000000000$$

Answer (score 0):

In the first degree, you have $5$ people, in the next, you'll have $5\cdot5=25$ people, and each degree onward increases by a multiple of $5$. All we need to find is the $n$ such that
$$5+25+125+\ldots+5^n>1,000,000,000.$$
I think you can try the rest on your own; you can use a calculator or a geometric series formula.